# Slick carousel inside other carousel - overflow and bug lazyloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I used slick carousel from http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

There is a product carousel, which on hover displays a box-shadow with a product, containing another carousel, which in turn displays the product variants. See a simple [demo here](http://codepen.io/jirka_kory/pen/yMBzwa).

These are the problems I have:

1. When I hover over a product, `overflow: hidden` has no effect in `slick-slider > slick-list`
2. Lazyloading with `ondemand` value does not work: when I click an arrow, main product images are not loaded. Though, when I change `lazyload` to `progressive`, everything is alright. But I need `ondemand` due to DOM content loading and total size.